# infinite activating state for custom build openssh-hpn-sshd on ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, systemd

I've compiled hpn version of openssh(OpenSSH_7.2p2-hpn14v11), sshd itself is working just fine. The problem is that every 2-3 minutes systemd restarts sshd as it doesn't get that service started properly. When I replace with Ubuntu's package of the same version it's working as it should. I've even tested on VM with clean install - same thing. What am I doing wrong?

> ```
>  ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server 
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
> Active: activating (start) since Wed 2016-09-28 20:18:49 EDT; 42s ago 
> Main PID: 24279 (sshd) 
> Tasks: 9 
> Memory: 6.8M 
> CPU: 164ms 
> CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service ├─20041 sshd: 
> root@pts/0 ├─20047 
> -bash ├─24279 
> /usr/sbin/sshd -D ├─24628 
> └─24629 pager
> Sep 28 20:18:49 hostname systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server... Sep 28 20:18:49 hostname sshd[24279]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22
> ```

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service


Logs:
    Sep 29 02:22:03 xxx sshd[15007]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Sep 29 02:22:03 xxx sshd[15007]: Server listening on :: port 22.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx sshd[15775]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
    Sep 29 02:23:33 xxx sshd[15775]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu backed down to use systemd-way of letting systemd know when it started. It is obvious from the option `Type=notify`, which makes impossible to use OpenSSH without Systemd patch. There are two possible solutions:

1. Change the line `Type=notify` to `Type=forking` and add a new line with `PIDFile=/var/run/sshd.pid` and `ExecStart` should be changed to `/usr/sbin/sshd $SSHD_OPTS`:

   ```
   Type=forking
   PIDFile=/var/run/sshd.pid
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd $SSHD_OPTS
   ```
2. Build your OpenSSH with the [patch](https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/commit/fe97848e044743f0bac019a491ddf0138f84e14a) from Debian/Ubuntu:

---

```
From fe97848e044743f0bac019a491ddf0138f84e14a Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Michael Biebl <biebl@debian.org>
Date: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 16:08:47 +0000
Subject: Add systemd readiness notification support

Bug-Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/778913
Forwarded: no
Last-Update: 2016-01-04

Patch-Name: systemd-readiness.patch
---
 configure.ac | 24 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 sshd.c       |  9 +++++++++
 2 files changed, 33 insertions(+)

diff --git a/configure.ac b/configure.ac
index f822fb3..6cafb15 100644
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -4319,6 +4319,29 @@ AC_ARG_WITH([kerberos5],
 AC_SUBST([GSSLIBS])
 AC_SUBST([K5LIBS])

+# Check whether user wants systemd support
+SYSTEMD_MSG="no"
+AC_ARG_WITH(systemd,
+   [  --with-systemd          Enable systemd support],
+   [ if test "x$withval" != "xno" ; then
+       AC_PATH_TOOL([PKGCONFIG], [pkg-config], [no])
+       if test "$PKGCONFIG" != "no"; then
+           AC_MSG_CHECKING([for libsystemd])
+           if $PKGCONFIG --exists libsystemd; then
+               SYSTEMD_CFLAGS=`$PKGCONFIG --cflags libsystemd`
+               SYSTEMD_LIBS=`$PKGCONFIG --libs libsystemd`
+               CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $SYSTEMD_CFLAGS"
+               SSHDLIBS="$SSHDLIBS $SYSTEMD_LIBS"
+               AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
+               AC_DEFINE(HAVE_SYSTEMD, 1, [Define if you want systemd support.])
+               SYSTEMD_MSG="yes"
+           else
+               AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
+           fi
+       fi
+   fi ]
+)
+
 # Looking for programs, paths and files

 PRIVSEP_PATH=/var/empty
@@ -5121,6 +5144,7 @@ echo "                   libedit support: $LIBEDIT_MSG"
 echo "  Solaris process contract support: $SPC_MSG"
 echo "           Solaris project support: $SP_MSG"
 echo "         Solaris privilege support: $SPP_MSG"
+echo "                   systemd support: $SYSTEMD_MSG"
 echo "       IP address in \$DISPLAY hack: $DISPLAY_HACK_MSG"
 echo "           Translate v4 in v6 hack: $IPV4_IN6_HACK_MSG"
 echo "                  BSD Auth support: $BSD_AUTH_MSG"
diff --git a/sshd.c b/sshd.c
index 837409b..868df9e 100644
--- a/sshd.c
+++ b/sshd.c
@@ -85,6 +85,10 @@
 #include <prot.h>
 #endif

+#ifdef HAVE_SYSTEMD
+#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
+#endif
+
 #include "xmalloc.h"
 #include "ssh.h"
 #include "ssh1.h"
@@ -2117,6 +2121,11 @@ main(int ac, char **av)
            unsetenv("SSH_SIGSTOP");
        }

+#ifdef HAVE_SYSTEMD
+       /* Signal systemd that we are ready to accept connections */
+       sd_notify(0, "READY=1");
+#endif
+
        /* Accept a connection and return in a forked child */
        server_accept_loop(&sock_in, &sock_out,
            &newsock, config_s);
```

Comment: As of today, 2019-08-14, this is still necessary, leastways on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The most current version of this patch is more or less the same. I manually copied and pasted around the same locations, as the codebase has changed. I'm sure this is low-hanging fruit for others, but if your a bit of a novice here--you'll also need to run `autoreconf` in order for the changes made to take (this rebuilds the "configure" file). Somewhat more obviously (to me anyway) you'll also want to install the headers for systemd (`apt install libsystemd-dev`) and give `./configure` the `--with-systemd` flag.

Comment: I wonder if 1. is still working (at least i haven't been able to have it working). Otherwise the patch (once applied manually) is still working on 2021-03-15 (still for hpn-ssh with a raw checkout of the "openssh-portable" source code).

Comment: Why don't we use `Type=simple` along with the sshd flag `-D`? It seems like it is working for me

Comment: Hi @Ashish. Using `Type=simple` is also an option, which might work for you, but will not work in some corner cases. We used this way in Fedora some time back (before https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/openssh/c/d1b43a28), but there were some issues as the systemd was not able to properly monitor the service and provide logs when the start/restart failed. I no longer know the details as I no longer work with OpenSSH, but more information should be available in the following bugzilla, which I fortunately linked from the above commit: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1291172

Answer (score 4):

As of today, 2019-10-28, this is still necessary on Ubuntu 19.04 compiling openssh-8.1p1.

You can find the latest version of the patch you need here: https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/blob/master/debian/patches/systemd-readiness.patch

You also need to install `pkg-config` (`apt-get install pkg-config`) else the `./configure --with-systemd` will not recognise the `libsystemd-dev` library neeed by the patch.

Answer (score -1):

There is another reason for the `sshd` OpenSSH Server being stuck in the "activating" state.

Namely, the cause could be "entropy exhaustion" which prevents the related OpenSSL module from getting initialized.

To verify that "entropy exhaustion" is really the problem, first stop the OpenSSH service, so it is no longer stuck in the "activating" state, by issuing the following command:

```
systemctl stop ssh
```

...after the `sshd` has stopped, issue the following command to start it again:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

...and observe the debug output for the following message:
*BTW: The `-ddd` option enables a verbose debug output during startup of the OpenSSH service.*

> random: N urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting

If this message appears after issuing the `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd` command, then it means, that the SSL module of the OpenSSH service cannot initialize because the entropy pool has been exhausted.

To remedy this problem, issue the command:

```
apt-get install haveged
```

..which will install a faster entropy source.  You can read more about `haveged` [**here**](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/faq.html).

This makes it a permanent fix.